# Why can I call an on-VPC aws lambda from an off-VPC aws lambda but not vice versa?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

So if I have two lambdas, one inside a private VPC, and one not on a VPC, calling the private lambda from inside the public lambda works but I cant call the public from the private lambda.

There's no NAT setup.

Why is this? It seems that I should not be able to call the private from the public theoretically.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In order to trigger a Lambda function, all that's required is for the caller to have outbound access to the [`Invoke`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html) AWS API. It is not necessary for the invoked Lambda function to have any open inbound ports, or any public Internet access.

So a public (non-VPC, has Internet access) Lambda function can call the `Invoke` API to trigger the private Lambda function, but the private VPC (no Internet access) Lambda function cannot access the `Invoke` API to trigger any Lambda function.

Comment: I wonder why this is not clearly stated in the AWS documentation

Comment: this answer saved me days of toil

Comment: Can the private VPC Lambda function be invoked synchronously such that it can return a value or can it only be invoked in an asynchronous way?

Comment: I don't understand how the second paragraph follows logically, with the word 'so', from the first. Why should it be the case that if all that's need is access to `Invoke`, a Lambda function in a VPC can't invoke one outside a VPC? There's a link in the logic chain missing from this answer.

Answer (score 8):

Inside VPC you need an AWS VPC interface endpoint (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-interface.html#create-interface-endpoint). It allows access to AWS Lambda service without going through the Internet.

Comment: This is a very helpful hint on this issue!

Comment: This is not working for me. I have a lambda inside a VPC. I also have VPC endpoints for Lambda and SES. From the lambda inside the VPC, I am unable to call SES as well as invoke a Lambda that is outside the VPC. Not to mention, the security group of the VPC lambda currently allows 0.0.0.0/0 traffic (this will be changed later) - but it is still not working.

Comment: You might need to enable private dns (very common problem). Also you might want to look into logs to understand the actual cause of the failure.

Comment: This resolved my issue. However, both lambdas are in the same VPC and Security Group.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue you may configure the lambda inside the VPC to have internet access. [This](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/) article explains how to set up this configuration.

Comment: NATs are the primary way, but we're all trying to avoid them because of the high price.